# [SwiftLint][Yaml][CustomRule] How to define a custom rule that applies on enum values

Tags: swiftlint

I'm trying to create a custom SwiftLint rule to ensure that all my enum values starts with a capital letter. As I'm really struggling with it and after I've searched a lot on internet without success, I'm asking it here.

Do you know how to implement such rule please ?

Thanks in advance.
Jb.